# assembly not found NEWBIE issue

Tags: c#

Just starting out with C# (using VS2008) - am an experienced Java, C++, VC++, VB programmer.

I downloaded an assembly (I guess) from codescales.com; it's a dll.

In my (new) C# project, I added this dll as a Reference -- by browsing to it.  I got intellisense working for it, and coded-up a simple example to test it, but everytime I hit the VS "Debug", I get the following Exception.  Do I need to "register" or do something to this downloaded DLL to use it properly in my project?  (VS seems to copy it to the output dir automatically on build.)

Thanks in advance,
AJ

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException was
>   unhandled   Message="Could not load
>   file or assembly 'CodeScales.Http,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified."
>   Source="ocrTest1"
>   FileName="CodeScales.Http,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null"   FusionLog="===
>   Pre-bind state information ===\r\nLOG:
>   User = CAPTURESDK-VM\XXXXX\r\nLOG:
>   DisplayName = CodeScales.Http,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null\n
>   (Fully-specified)\r\nLOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Documents and
>   Settings/XXXXX/My Documents/Visual
>   Studio
>   2008/Projects/ocrTest1/ocrTest1/bin/Debug/\r\nLOG:
>   Initial PrivatePath = NULL\r\nCalling
>   assembly : ocrTest1, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null.\r\n===\r\nLOG:
>   This bind starts in default load
>   context.\r\nLOG: No application
>   configuration file found.\r\nLOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.\r\nLOG:
>   Policy not being applied to reference
>   at this time (private, custom,
>   partial, or location-based assembly
>   bind).\r\nLOG: Attempting download of
>   new URL file:///C:/Documents and
>   Settings/XXXXX/My Documents/Visual
>   Studio
>   2008/Projects/ocrTest1/ocrTest1/bin/Debug/CodeScales.Http.DLL.\r\nLOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Documents and
>   Settings/XXXXX/My Documents/Visual
>   Studio
>   2008/Projects/ocrTest1/ocrTest1/bin/Debug/CodeScales.Http/CodeScales.Http.DLL.\r\nLOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Documents and
>   Settings/XXXXX/My Documents/Visual
>   Studio
>   2008/Projects/ocrTest1/ocrTest1/bin/Debug/CodeScales.Http.EXE.\r\nLOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Documents and
>   Settings/XXXXX/My Documents/Visual
>   Studio
>   2008/Projects/ocrTest1/ocrTest1/bin/Debug/CodeScales.Http/CodeScales.Http.EXE.\r\n"

Answer (score 5):

There's a name mismatch, not sure how that happened.  Remove the assembly reference.  Rename the DLL you downloaded from CodeScales.Http.V0.14.dll to CodeScales.Http.dll.  Then add the reference back.

Comment: Well spotted. I didn't read the error closely enough. Basically it looks liks CodeScales is attempting to use the filename for versioning, which doesn't really work for .NET assemblies...

Answer (score 4):

You need to change Framework. Go to 'Properties' and the change '.Net Framework 4 Client profile' to '.Net Framework 4'.